# UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete automatically deselects all visible cells in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use a grouped UITableView with implemented commitEditingStyle to delete a single row from the table. (In my UIViewController, no UITableViewController).
Also i use a Custom Cell with an checked image. To change the image i simply use this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    if (selected) {
        self.img_checked.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];

    else {
        self.img_checked.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
    }
}
```

My problem is, when is swipe a row the "DELETE" appears as desired, but it automatically deselects all visible cells in the tableview

How can i prevent the tableview from doing this?

Comment: why you want to keep cell selected?

Comment: There a 5 selected, visible Rows in my tableview. if i swipe for delete, setSelected gets automatically called by all visible rows. Sure i want to let the other rows selected, i even do not touch them at all, the one I'm deleting i dont care, its deleted ;) but also if i just swie and cancel the deletion, all rows stay unselected

Answer (score 1):

You should save indexes or indexpaths of selected states and then check it in cellForRow or willDisplayCell: delegates. You can make it via dictionary or array. The second way is to save it in separate variable inside the object you're setting in the cell(if you do so).

Comment: Why should i save them? If you select a cell the state is already saved in each Cell. But i ask myself, why is the - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated method beeing called? I dont select any of the visible rows. in the moment i swipe one row, all visible rows get deselected, because iOS calls that method automatically.  So for full usability with all features, the standard apple callback method for selecting cells is useless?

Comment: It is an interface selection, but you need to tell the system what cell should be selected by yourself, check this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html